# Email greeting settings for contacts without names

Tags: contacts

Contacts have an 'email greeting' field which can be customised on a per-contact basis, and takes its default from a pattern like `Dear {contact.first_name}`  [docs link](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/contacts/#greetings-and-addressee-fields)

Is it possible to enter a pattern that will show "Supporter" if there is no first name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Smarty conditionals in greetings](https://civicrm.org/blog/antrik/enhancing-greetings-handling) in CiviCRM 4.5+.

So the correct pattern would be:

```
{capture assign=first_name}{contact.first_name}{/capture}Dear {$first_name|default:Supporter},
```

Comment: This is a good answer as it does not require any PHP coding or installing extensions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do just by configuring that pattern, but you could [write your own token](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/#custom-mail-merge-token).

Comment: Thanks @Aidan I made [this](https://github.com/artfulrobot/dearyou) (which one day would be good to merge with the Fancy Tokens extension)

Comment: That's a nice bit of work! @artfulrobot